# Ubuntu apache virtual host site doesn't work in the browser

Tags: laravel, apache, vhosts

I have a Laravel site that I've setup in `/var/www/html/`. I have also setup a vhost for this site as I want to have a custom url(**example.dev**) rather than `localhost`.

This is how I setup my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.dev
    ServerAlias http://example.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public/

        <Directory /var/www/html/example/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

After doing this I disable the default .conf by running `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf` and then I enable the .conf I created(`sudo a2ensite example.dev.conf`). After all this I restarted apache and reloaded the configurations.

From there on I went to add my server name to my host file like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost       example.dev
127.0.1.1       tangaye

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Now when I try to access my site in the browser my typing `example.dev` I get:

> This site cannot be reached. example.dev refuse to connect.

But when I do `localhost` my site is launch. Why is this happening? Interestingly I have realized that when I `curl -L example.dev` I get the full expected outcome of my site in the terminal.
Why is me site being access in the terminal rather than the browser? Will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly thanks to @Bekir for the [heads up](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/). I realized google has added `.dev` as one of their Top Level Domiains(tld). Which means if one tries to use it locally one local machine should be able to:

- Serve HTTPs
- Have self-signed certificates in place to handle that
- Have that self-signed certificate added to your local trust store (you can't dismiss self-signed certificates with HSTS, they need to be 'trusted' by your computer)

As mentioned in the [post](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) there are two options: `.localhost` or `.test`. Both of these resolves to `127.0.0.1`.

I tried both and it worked perfectly for me. I also try `.com` but it only work on **opera** and not on **chrome**.

On **chrome** I realize forces `https` when I'm using `example.com` or `example.dev`, but everthing works fine across browsers when I switch to `example.test` or `example.localhost`